# Can't bind client to local IP, another IP is used silently

Tags: ip, source, slackware

Due to a firewall on a server, I need to make all connections to it from a host (Slackware64 linux 14.2, kernel 5.4) using allowed source IP, **10.2.23.1** in this case.

IP addresses on host:

```
$ ip a
[...]
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:b9:55:c1:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.22.7/28 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:b9ff:fe55:c1c8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:b9:55:c1:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.16.166/30 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:b9ff:fe55:c1c9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:b9:55:c1:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.23.1/24 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.247.226.186/32 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:b9ff:fe55:c1ca/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
```

For example, using SSH, I want to connect to 10.0.4.16 from local IP 10.2.23.1:

```
$ ssh -b 10.2.23.1 admin@10.0.4.16
```

The connection fails, because ssh uses 10.247.226.186 as a source IP, not 10.2.23.1 as it should (confirmed with tcpdump) - and that isn't allowed on server. Of course I could allow another IP on server, but I want to know **WHY** it doesn't work.

I also wrote a simple C program confirming this (really only `socket`, `bind` to 10.2.23.1 and `connect` to ... anywhere in fact). The program runs, no errors from `bind` function, but the source IP is always 10.247.226.186.

Does anyone have any clue why all connections use **the other IP** on eth2? Could be the /32 netmask the problem?

Thank you.

EDIT: Added the host OS.

Comment: If you are going to have a /32 address, then put it on a dummy interface. `modprobe dummy` should load the kernel module.

Comment: Does this command also behave the same? `socat -d -d tcp4:10.0.4.16:22,bind=10.2.23.1 -` Can you compare its debug output and tcpdump's output? Or you could compare `ss -atn dport 22` while ssh is attempted with tcpdump's output if you can't use socat. If they differ, then firewall/nat rules come to mind. If that's the case, can you provide your ruleset? eg: `nft list ruleset` or `iptables-save -c`

Comment: Oh this is embarsasing... It was NATing firewall. College of mine changed firewall rules and I didn't see it between other rules. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Like A.B said in comments, it was NAT on host. That is the reason all programs were able to bind to IP but tcpdump showed different IP.